# CSS3 Bootstrap 4 How to handle theinput error message with inline inputs

Tags: css, vue.js, vee-validate

I have currently 2 input fields on the same line to be validated with vee-validate (I am using Vue.js).

[image: form inputs]

The validation message is displayed at the end of the `input-group`, not inside it.

[image: form inputs error]

Here is the html code:

```
<div class="form-group row d-flex justify-content-center">
  <div class="input-group input-group-lg col-md-3" >
    <input v-validate="'required'" name="username" v-model="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" aria-label="Name">
     <span v-show="errors.has('username')" class="help is-danger">{{ errors.first('username') }}</span>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group input-group-lg col-md-4" >
    <input v-validate="'required|email'" name="email" v-model="email" type="text" :class="{'input': true, 'is-danger': errors.has('email') }" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email Address" aria-label="Email">
     <span v-show="errors.has('email')" class="help is-danger">{{ errors.first('email') }}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Bootstrap `.help-block` class in your error text.

Comment: Thanks ed1nh0..; tried it . ( see my update  below the question...  no change in the display . it seems thet the input-group is resized to accomodate the input field ( reduced size) and the p paragraph w the message ..

Comment: Got it ...   need to remove the input-goup which using flex ... I tried to set it to flex: none; but it does not change its behavior...